# How to obtain Google Maps API key

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, key

We have been using Google maps API for drivng directions on our web site.

As we have learned the hard way, Google no longer supports the old v2 API and key (everything seems to work, but all attempts to obtain driving directions via e.g. `mygdirobject.load("from: N50.734777 E5.3366944 to: Foo Bar Baz@50.745873,5.391617",G_TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING)` result in "Error 602" though they used to work properly).

To make a transition to v3, the first step is to obtain a v3 key.
Google's documentation as well as several questions here suggest to log in with my Google account to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and "Click the Services link from the left-hand menu."

However, there is no such thing as a "Services" entry (or anything with a suitable German translation in my case) on anything that could be called menu (left-hand or otherwise) an an almost empty page.
What am I supposed to make of this?

Comment: Recently there has been an update  for the console, the most descriptions you'll find in the web(also on e.g. the API-documentations provided by google) are related to the old console. In the new console you'll find a link at the bottom "Return to original console " ...use this link.

Comment: @Dr.Molle The new console was not displayed either - but see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple - and somewhat entertaining even.

Ever read that Google may become angry if you try to serve different content to Google's indexing box than to "real" users? Which in effect tells you not to implement `user-agent` based switching?
Ever learned the security mantra that one should never rely on data submitted by the user (such as `user-agent`) to be accurate? And the javascript best practice to check for the availability of special features by testing for the existence of the corresponding objects and *not* by inspecting the `user-agent` string?

Well, guess what: If one tampers with one's `user-agent` string, the page does not load all content and at some other places suspects your browser is too old though it doen't even check if this is true (after all not displaying that message would remove one option to promote chrome).

Sorry, if this is a bit of a rant, but really: With the original manufacturer user-agent-string, everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **APIs** link or something to that effect, link should look as such:

```
https://cloud.google.com/console#/project/<PROJECT_ID>/apiui/api
```

In there you should see "On/Off" switches for all the APIs. If you prefer to see the English link names so you can follow along a specific tutorial, then tack on this URL parameter in the address bar and hit enter or reload button in the browser:
**&hl=en-US**

Adding that to the URL forces English language menus.

Comment: Nothing like that got displayed - but see my answer below for the reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new project (or go into an existing project, then once in the project options navigate to APIs & auth menu.From here you should see a list of toggle switches to enable the maps V3 api.

Then navigate to Credentials and there you can generate a new API key/view your existing one.

[image: google api location]

Comment: That would have been fine if anything like that were displayed - it was once I found the reason behind the problem, see my answer